# Saving and Reloading an R workspace image in Eclipse StatET

Tags: eclipse, r, statet

Fairly simple question hopefully, as far as I could tell most similar questions were about preventing save prompt. I have Eclipse setup to work with StatET, Sweave, and R quite happily. I followed http://jeromyanglim.blogspot.com/2010/02/getting-started-with-sweave-r-latex.html guide. The only problem I have is how to reload a workspace image that contains variables etc.

I chose yes to save the workspace image, but I'm not sure how to reload it. load() doesn't work, and I have no idea what the default savename is.

Any suggestions?

Comment: my shameless self-promotion is the knitr package: http://yihui.name/knitr/ You can use cache instead of loading a whole workspace; the latter is less efficient. One knitr user told me a few days ago she could make a simple demo for using knitr in Eclipse, so stay tuned if you are interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default "savename" should be something like .Rdata or .Rda and it will go to your current working directory. If you are on a Mac or Windows device the default may be to hide such files from "visibility" from your system file browser, although you should be able to use file.choose() in any place where you would be specifying a file name. I don't understand how you "save a workspace image" that cannot be load()-ed unless what your really mean is cannot be found. See if you can find it with:

```
load(file.choose() )
```

To get better answers you should include information about your OS and the code you are having problems with.

Comment: `file.choose()` is handy for novices, but I'm almost always against using it because it requires manual operations, hence it is not a reproducible command especially in the context of Sweave. A better way is to always know your working directory, and `load('foobar.RData')` explicitly after `save.image('foobar.RData')`

Comment: I only offered it because of the concern for hidden system files and the fact that the questioner didn't give enough details to make me think @lanagi was _not_ a novice. I used to use it but now I use full file paths and names myself.

Comment: I also found this answer in the comments, much the same as @DWin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3612522/r-workspaces-i-e-r-files.
Using Eclipse and StatET I found that using the default save (.RData) and then trying to load using load() actually didn't work as I got a "File not specified" error. Defaults do work however if you load(".RData"). Thanks for the answers.

Comment: what if i have a graph (in eclipse + statet along R) i want to save as a *.jpg file and use independtly of R and related programs?

Comment: @edouard I do not see the connection of your question to this topic. A "workspace image" is not a graphical term. It is the contents of a workspace saved in a form that can be restored to continue working with the same data structures.

Comment: sorry, i didn't get there is no connection. thanks for explaining what is a workspace image